# TypeScript/Cypress command which accept only defined value of parameter

Tags: javascript, typescript, parameters, cypress

I wrote cypress command with parameter and I would like to change it that function accept only certain values, e.g. I would like that `columnValue` can be only 'xxx' or 'yyy' or 'zzz'. How can I do it?

```js
Cypress.Commands.add('addColumnAsDimension', (columnName: string) => {
  chartMenu.addColumnButton.click();
  chartMenu.columnNameButton(columnName).click();
  chartMenu.addAsDimensionButton.click();
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [union type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) for that:

```js
type Column = 'xxx' | 'yyy' | 'zzz'

Cypress.Commands.add('addColumnAsDimension', (columnName: Column) => {
  chartMenu.addColumnButton.click();
  chartMenu.columnNameButton(columnName).click();
  chartMenu.addAsDimensionButton.click();
});
```

Also, if you want the complier to check your custom Cypress method invocation, you have to  add a [type definition](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/tooling/typescript-support#Types-for-custom-commands) for the method as well:

```js
declare namespace Cypress {
  interface Chainable<Subject> {
       addColumnAsDimension(columnName: Column): void
    }
}
```

Now the compiler checks your arguments:
[image]